# How to restrict user to run and use only one program running on my server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, remote-desktop

I have a cloud server running windows-server-2008 and i want my customer to log in to the server using remote desktop and the customer can run my own program only , he should not be able to run any other program (web browsers , notepad , sqlserver , ...).
so how to implement this ?
 what i need to install and what the configurations i need to add?

thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to look in local *Group Policy* settings for locking down applications and the server. Local Group Policy is included with Server 2008 as standard so it's just a case of finding the settings and tweaking them as nessecary. Software Restriction Policies should take care of which programs are allowed to run and which are not.

Bear in mind Group Policy can be a complex beast but Microsoft does have many useful resources out there.